# Django-Voting: Solving AttributeError

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to implement [Django Reddit Style Voting](http://code.google.com/p/django-voting/wiki/RedditStyleVoting) into my project. I have been searching the internet the past few days trying to piece together how to make it happen, but am unclear about how to set up my urlconf to handle `confirm_vote.html`, and what the contents of that file may be? The error that I get when I click to vote is:

```
Generic vote view must be called with either post_vote_redirect, a 
"next" parameter in the request, or the object being voted on must 
define a get_absolute_url method or property.
```

Which corresponds with [This Part of Django-Votings' Code](https://github.com/brosner/django-voting/blob/master/voting/views.py#L76-82). I have set my project up almost identically to the example project listed on the Github page.

I realize that I need to set-up a confirm_vote.html page, and have done a lot of searching to find out how to set up the urlconf to deal with it. I found [This Blog Post](http://www.justinlilly.com/python/django_voting.html), but it doesnt seem to answer my question.

Can anyone help me figure out what to put in confirm_vote.html and the url regex to deal with it? Thanks for helping!

EDIT

---

Actually just realized that the urlconf for confirm_vote.html is on the sample tutorial.

```
(r'^links/(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<direction>up|down|clear)vote/?$',
    vote_on_object, dict(model=Link, template_object_name='link',
        template_name='kb/link_confirm_vote.html',
        allow_xmlhttprequest=True)),
```

But still confused about the `AttributeError` and the contents of `confirm_vote.html.` Thanks for any ideas!

EDIT: link_list.html

---

```
url(r'^links/?$', object_list, dict(queryset=Link.objects.all(),
    template_object_name='link', template_name='links/link_list.html',
    paginate_by=15, allow_empty=True)),



{% for link in link_list %}<tr class="{% cycle odd,even %}">
<td class="vote">

  {% dict_entry_for_item link from vote_dict as vote %}
  {% dict_entry_for_item link from score_dict as score %}

  <form class="linkvote" id="linkup{{ link.id }}" action="/links/{{ link.id }}/{% if vote and vote.is_upvote %}clear{% else %}up{% endif %}vote/" method="POST">
    <input type="image" id="linkuparrow{{ link.id }}" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}img/aup{% if vote and vote.is_upvote %}mod{% else %}grey{% endif %}.png">
    {% csrf_token %}
  </form>

  <form class="linkvote" id="linkdown{{ link.id }}" action="/links/{{ link.id }}/{% if vote and vote.is_downvote %}clear{% else %}down{% endif %}vote/" method="POST">
    <input type="image" id="linkdownarrow{{ link.id }}" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}img/adown{% if vote and vote.is_downvote %}mod{% else %}grey{% endif %}.png">
    {% csrf_token %}
  </form>

</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not passing the `?next=http://example.com/return_to_this_page_after_vote/` in your URL (not urls.py) which hits the `vote_on_object` view. Please check your template or post it here.

**For Information:**
Instead you could use [django-ratings](https://github.com/dcramer/django-ratings) before reinventing the wheel. It's easy to use and to implement.

---

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
<form class="linkvote" id="linkup{{ link.id }}" action="/links/{{ link.id }}/{% if vote and vote.is_upvote %}clear{% else %}up{% endif %}vote/?next=/" method="POST">
    <input type="image" id="linkuparrow{{ link.id }}" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}img/aup{% if vote and vote.is_upvote %}mod{% else %}grey{% endif %}.png">
    {% csrf_token %}
  </form>

  <form class="linkvote" id="linkdown{{ link.id }}" action="/links/{{ link.id }}/{% if vote and vote.is_downvote %}clear{% else %}down{% endif %}vote/?next=/" method="POST">
    <input type="image" id="linkdownarrow{{ link.id }}" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}img/adown{% if vote and vote.is_downvote %}mod{% else %}grey{% endif %}.png">
    {% csrf_token %}
  </form>
```

I've only added `?next=/` to the end of the action. I'm not sure if it will work - but just give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your response @init3. I added the template that I have so far, but not sure how to pass the url in the template.   On your other point, is it possible to configure django-ratings to score in a Stack Overflow / Digg / Reddit style? Thanks for your comments!

Comment: django-ratings: as i can see it in the code it should be possible - but I haven't tried it by myself

Comment: Thanks @init3. I missed that. Let me check that out and I'll post back asap. I appreciate your thoughts